# Sources of inspiration for navigation breadcrumbs

Tags: html, css, design-patterns, navigation

I'm looking for sources of inspiration and/or design patterns for navigation 'breadcrumbs'. So far I have found the [breadcrumb collection on Pattern Tap](http://patterntap.com/tap/collection/breadcrumbs). Does anyone know of any other sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.greepit.com/2009/02/06/breadcrumb-inspiration-for-designers/

Answer (score 5):

The article '[Taming lists](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/)' from A List Apart has some good advice on CSS styling for breadcrumbs (look down for the heading 'Breadcrumb Trails').

Comment: Classic article, I remember when it was first published. Those were heady, exciting times.

Answer (score 3):

The [Yahoo pattern library](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/pattern.php?pattern=breadcrumbs) has a useful wee bit about breadcrumbs too.

Answer (score 1):

I found a few good/bad examples of breadcrumbs [here](http://www.designvsart.com/blog/2008/02/06/good-bread-crumbs-bad-bread-crumbs/).

Also, there's a blog post about [breadcrumb designs](http://f6design.com/journal/2007/02/09/the-humble-breadcrumb/).

Answer (score 1):

There's a great page on breadcrumbs at the [Diemen Repository of Interaction Design Patterns](http://visiblearea.com/cgi-bin/twiki/view/Patterns/Homeward_path)

Answer (score 1):

Smashing Magazine also has a decent roundup:

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/17/breadcrumbs-in-web-design-examples-and-best-practices-2/

Answer (score 0):

If using Microsoft ASP.NET, there's a built in control: [SiteMapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x20z8c51.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[Web & Patterns breadcrumbs category](http://web-patterns.net/category/breadcrumbs/)

"Inspirational and creative Breadcrumbs for web design"